# Why do my divs go out of position whenever they get any content?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have my divs in a tic tac toe sort of way, where it’s just a 3 by 3 grid, and it works fine, just until I type in a letter or something inside the div. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

```css
body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: Arial 14px;
}

#blocks {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

#canvas {
  margin-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <div id="blocks"></div>
  <div id="blocks"></div>
  <div id="blocks"></div><br>
  <div id="blocks"></div>
  <div id="blocks"></div>
  <div id="blocks"></div><br>
  <div id="blocks"></div>
  <div id="blocks"></div>
  <div id="blocks"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: another side note, inline-block is a terrible way in creating "grids". either do it with flexbox or better yet CSS-Grid

Comment: vertical-align:top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `margin-bottom` to the divs.

```css
body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: Arial 14px;
}

#blocks {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-bottom:6px;
}

#canvas {
  margin-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <div id="blocks">x</div>
  <div id="blocks">x</div>
  <div id="blocks">x</div><br>
  <div id="blocks">o</div>
  <div id="blocks">o</div>
  <div id="blocks">o</div><br>
  <div id="blocks">x</div>
  <div id="blocks">o</div>
  <div id="blocks">x</div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesnt work when you not change the ids to classes as it still only applies to the first element.

Comment: @tacoshy What do you mean?

Comment: if you apply it to `#blocks` then it only applies to the first element with that id as the ID is not unique in this invalid HTML markup. So either use `#canvas > div` as a selector or change the ID's to Classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use grid or flexbox. Something like this:

```css
body,
html {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: Arial 14px;
}

.blocks {
  background-color: red;
  /* Center content within each cell */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#canvas {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  /* Achieve layout using grid */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <div class="blocks"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="blocks"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="blocks"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="blocks"><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="blocks"><span>5</span></div>
  <div class="blocks"><span>6</span></div>
  <div class="blocks"><span>7</span></div>
  <div class="blocks"><span>8</span></div>
  <div class="blocks"><span>9</span></div>
</div>
```

I changed the `blocks` ids to classes. Also added some styles of my own to center the content inside each grid cell (added `span` tags within each cell `div` for that).

Comment: a lot of superflous css delcarations. giving the the `. blocks { display: block; display: flex; }` as example. Then using `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);`while also adding a width directly to the grid-cards. better yet simply remove width and hight from the cards and define it with grid-templates. Also no need to add spans

Comment: @tacoshy I added the span tags so that I could use flexbox to center the content within each cell (horizontally and vertically). I don't see any `display: block` declaration. I have edited my answer to integrate the rest of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```css
body {
  font : Arial 14px;
  }
#canvas {
  --sz_blk : 50px;
  --in_blk : 6px;
  width    : calc((var(--sz_blk) * 3) + (var(--in_blk) * 6));
  margin   : auto;
  }
#canvas > div {
  background-color : red;
  width            : var(--sz_blk);
  height           : var(--sz_blk);
  margin           : var(--in_blk);
  display          : block;
  float            : left;
  text-align       : center;
  line-height      : calc(var(--sz_blk) / 5 * 4) 
  }
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>o</div>
  <div>o</div>
  <div>o</div>
  <div>x</div>
  <div>o</div>
  <div>x</div>
</div>
```